# Editing tumblr theme html to remove some elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, tumblr

This is my tumblr url(custom domain): 
[http://intchauhan.com/](http://intchauhan.com)

**I want to remove "Follow intchauhan" and "tumblr." buttons that are on the right side.**

This is the html of the theme 
:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

  <meta name="color:Background" content="#ffffff"/>
  <meta name="color:Title" content="#000000"/>
  <meta name="color:Text" content="#202020"/>
  <meta name="color:Minor text" content="#999999"/>
  <meta name="color:Line" content="#EEEEEE"/>
  <meta name="color:Link" content="#49D28D"/>
  <meta name="color:Link hover" content="#3FB67A"/>
<meta name="color:Top line" content="#eeeeee"/>
<meta name="color:Bottom line" content="#eeeeee"/>
<meta name="color:Notes background" content="#f7f7f7"/>
<meta name="if:Center all" content="0"/> 
<meta name="if:Center links" content="1"/>   
<meta name="if:Large Photoset" content="0"/>
<meta name="font:Heading" content="Futura"/>
<meta name="image:Header" content="0">
<meta name="if:Show notes on permalink pages" content="1">
<meta name="if:Ask Link" content="0" />
<meta name="if:Submit Link" content="0" />
<meta name="if:Stretch small images" content="0" />


<meta name="text:Caption size" content="14px"/>
<meta name="text:Title size" content="20px"/>
<meta name="text:Header size" content="85px"/>


<meta name="font:Description" content="Georgia"/>
<meta name="font:Body" content="Georgia"/>

<meta name="text:Disqus Shortname" content=""/>

  <title>{Title}{block:PostSummary}: {PostSummary}{/block:PostSummary}</title>
  {block:Description}<meta name="description" content="{MetaDescription}"/>{/block:Description}

  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{Favicon}"/>
  <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS" href="{RSS}"/>

  <style type="text/css">
body,div,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,code,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,th,td,form,fieldset,legend,input,textarea{margin:0;padding:0;}
html{font-size:{text:Caption size};}
table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
fieldset,img{border:0;}
caption,cite,code,dfn,th,var{font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-size:12px;font-weight:normal; padding:5px 0;}
abbr,acronym{border:0;}

body {background:{color:Background}; color:{color:Text}; font:1em/1.5 {font:Body}; margin:0 0 0 0;}

h1, h3 {font-family:{font:Heading};}
pre,code {font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif}

a:link, a:visited {color:{color:Link}; text-decoration:none;}
a:hover, a:active {color:{color:Link hover};}



#header {color:{color:Minor text}; position:relative; margin:-49 auto; padding-top:40px; width:875px;}

#header h1 {color:{color:Title}; font-weight:bold; text-align:center; font-size:{text:Header size}; line-height:90%; margin-bottom:30px; margin-top:-30px;
            letter-spacing:-1px;}
#header h1 a:link, #header h1 a:visited {color:{color:Title}; display:block;}
#header h1 a:hover, #header h1 a:active {color:{color:Link hover};}
#description {font-family:{font:Description}; font-size:{text:Caption size}; text-align:center; line-height:autopx; margin-bottom:20px; margin-top:-5px;}
#header form {margin-bottom:20px;}
#header form input {width:630px;}
#header ul {margin:0 -0.25em 1.5em;}
#header li {list-style:none; text-transform:lowercase;}
#header li a {background:{color:Background}; display:block; padding:0 0.25em;
              text-decoration:none;}
#header li a:hover {background:none;}

#container {background-color:{color:Container}; margin:30px auto; padding-top:5px; width:875px}



#container .box img {
          max-width: 100%;
        }

.logo {
    border:0;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    max-width:875px;
}

.single { width:875px; margin-bottom:10px;}

#posts {background-color:{color:Background}; border-top:1px solid {color:Top line}; 
        border-bottom:1px solid {color:Bottom line}; margin:0px; padding:0px; {block:IfCenterall}text-align:center;{/block:IfCenterall}font-size:{text:Caption size};}


#posts .post {list-style:none; padding-bottom:10px; max-width:875px;
              clear:both;}
#posts .content {color:{color:Text}; padding:0; margin-left:0px;}

#footer {margin:0 auto; max-width:875px; padding-bottom:30px;}
#pagination p {font-size:{text:Caption size}; min-width:150px; line-height:autopx; margin:0 0 10px;
               white-space:nowrap;}
#pagination p.back {display:inline; text-align:right; float:right; margin-left:20px;}
#pagination p.forward {display:inline; float:left; margin-right:1.5em;}
#pagination a {font-style:italic;}
#pagination .page {text-align:center; font:12px {font:Body};
                   margin-bottom:20px; text-transform:lowercase;}
#credits {clear:both; display:inline; text-align:center; font-size:12px; color:{color:Minor text}; margin:0; padding:1.5em 0;}
#footer a:hover, #footer a:active {text-decoration:none;}

p {margin-bottom:25px;}
form .submit {height:0; overflow:hidden; display:block;}

.meta {float:left; clear:left; {block:IfCenterall}width:875px{/block:IfCenterall}; font-size:14px; text-align:left; line-height:10px;}
.meta h2 {font-size:14px; margin-bottom:5px; border-bottom:1px solid {color:Line};}
.meta h2 a {text-decoration:none; display:block; padding:0px 0px;}
.meta h2 a:hover {background:none;}
.meta p {color:{color:Minor text}; font-style:italic; margin:0 0 0 1em;
         text-indent:-0.75em; text-transform:lowercase;}
p.meta {color:{color:Minor text}; font-style:italic; margin:0;
        width:150px; text-indent:-0.75em; text-transform:lowercase;}
.meta a {font-style:normal; white-space:nowrap;}
.meta .plays {font-weight:bold; font-style:normal;}

h3 {font-size:{text:Title size}; line-height:autopx; padding-bottom:20px; font-weight:bold;}

.content a {border-bottom:1px solid {color:Line};}
.content a:hover {border-bottom-width:2px;}
.content .photo a {border:none !important;}
.content ul, .content ol {margin:20px;}
.content ul li {list-style:square;}

blockquote {margin:0 20px 20px; font-style:italic;}
blockquote i, blockquote em, blockquote [lang="ja"] {font-style:normal;}
pre, code {font-size:10px; line-height:12px;}
pre {background:#e1e1e1; margin:15px; padding:10px;
     overflow-x:auto;}
pre code {display:block;}
pre i, code i {font-style:normal; color:{color:Minor text};}

ins {text-decoration:none; font-style:italic;}
blockquote ins, em ins, ins em {font-style:normal;}

abbr, acronym, .caps {font-size:12px; letter-spacing:0.1em; word-spacing:0.1em;}
abbr, acronym {text-transform:uppercase;}
.caps {text-transform:uppercase;}

.text {margin-bottom:20px;} 
.caption {margin-bottom:20px;} 
.nocaption {margin-bottom:-20px;} 
.vidcaption {margin-top:120px;}

.post img, .post object, .post embed {max-width:100%; {block:IfStretchsmallimages}
                width: 875px;
                {/block:IfStretchsmallimages}}

.link-post h3 {padding:0; margin-bottom:18px;}

.photo-post .photo {margin-bottom:19px; margin-top:20px; }
.video-post .video {margin-bottom:0px; margin-top:20px; }

.quote-post .quote {font-family:{font:Body};}
.quote-post .source, .cite
  {float:right; margin:0 0 35px 0; text-indent:-1.5em;}
.quote-post .source a:first-child, .cite
  {letter-spacing:0;}
.short-quote .quote, .medium-quote .quote, .long-quote .quote
  {font-size:{text:Title size}; line-height:autopx; margin:10px 40px 20px 0;}


.audio-post .audio { 
    display: block;
    width:875px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;}





.chat-post ol {list-style:none; margin:15px 0;}
.chat-post li {margin-left:1.5em; text-indent:-1.5em;}
.chat-post .label {font-weight:bold; padding-right:0.125em;}
.chat-post .speaker {font-style:italic;}
.chat-post .speaker2 .label, .chat-post .speaker4 .label,
  .chat-post .speaker6 .label, .chat-post .speaker8 .label
    {color:{color:Minor text};}
.chat-post .speaker3 .label, .chat-post .speaker4 .label,
  .chat-post .speaker7 .label, .chat-post .speaker8 .label
    {text-transform:uppercase; letter-spacing:0.1em;}
.chat-post .speaker5 .label, .chat-post .speaker6 .label,
  .chat-post .speaker7 .label, .chat-post .speaker8 .label
    {font-family:{font:Heading};}


.day .month {text-transform:uppercase;}
{block:DayPage}.day {font-weight:bold;}{/block:DayPage}

.content.text-post img {
max-width: 100%;
}


.multi {margin-bottom:30px; margin-right:15px; {block:IfCenterall}margin-right:10px; margin-left:10px;{/block:IfCenterall};}


.video embed, .video object, .video iframe {width:875px; height:500px; margin-bottom:-100px;}


.wide_audio iframe {width:875px; }


#comment {
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 18px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#comment a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: {color:Caption};
}

#comment a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: {color:Link Hover};
}

#dsq-content {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .30);
  background: url('     ');
  padding: 5px 20px 20px 20px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}



a.single_links:last-child { margin-right:0px; }

a.single_links 
{display: inline-block; list-style-type: none; margin-right:20px;}




{block:PermalinkPage}



      p.answer_form_container { width: 512px; }

      ol.notes { width: 875px; list-style-type: none; margin:20px auto; padding: 0; }
        ol.notes li.note { background: {color:Notes background}; margin: 0 0 0px 0; padding: 0 4px; }
        ol.notes a { color: {color:Links In Notes}; }
        ol.notes img.avatar { display: none; }
        ol.notes blockquote { margin: 0; }
          ol.notes blockquote a { text-decoration: none; }
    {/block:PermalinkPage}






a.install {
        width: 96px;
        height: 20px;
        background: url(http://static.tumblr.com/thpaaos/dHHkt0jor/install_theme.png);
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 26px;
        right: 3px;
    }


a {
  outline: none;
}





{CustomCSS}
  </style>


<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


{block:IfLargePhotoset}

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
$(".photoset").each(function() {
    $(this).width('875px');
    var newSrc = $(this).attr("src").replace('700','875');
    $(this).attr("src", newSrc);
});


$(function(){
var iFrames = $('.photoset');

function iResize() {
    for (var i = 0, j = iFrames.length; i < j; i++) {
        iFrames[i].style.height = iFrames[i].contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';}
    }

    if ($.browser.safari || $.browser.opera) { 
        iFrames.load(function(){
            setTimeout(iResize, 0); 
        });

        for (var i = 0, j = iFrames.length; i < j; i++) {
            var iSource = iFrames[i].src;
            iFrames[i].src = '';
            iFrames[i].src = iSource;
        }
    } else {
        iFrames.load(function() {
            this.style.height = this.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';
        });
    }
});
});
</script>

{/block:IfLargePhotoset}




</head>
<body>

<div id="container">


<div id="header">
  <a href="/">
        {block:IfHeaderImage}<h1><img src="{image:Header}" class="logo" /></h1>{/block:IfHeaderImage}
        {block:IfNotHeaderImage}<h1>{Title}</h1>{/block:IfNotHeaderImage}</a>



  {block:Description}<p id="description">
    {Description}
  </p>{/block:Description}

<p>
{block:IfCenterlinks}<center>{/block:IfCenterlinks}


{block:HasPages}{block:Pages}

<a class="single_links" href="{URL}">{Label}</a>

{/block:Pages}{/block:HasPages}

{block:SubmissionsEnabled}{block:IfSubmitlink}
            <a class="single_links" href="/submit">{SubmitLabel}</a><br>
        {/block:IfSubmitlink}{/block:SubmissionsEnabled}

{block:AskEnabled}{block:IfAskLink}
<a class="single_links" href="/ask">{AskLabel}</a>
{/block:IfAskLink}{/block:AskEnabled}


{block:IfCenterlinks}</center>{/block:IfCenterlinks}</p>


</div>



<ol id="posts"><br>

{block:Posts}


<li class="post" id="post{PostID}">

    {block:Text}

 <div class="meta">


{block:IfCenterall}<center>{/block:IfCenterall}<h2>
<a title="link to this post" href="{Permalink}">{DayOfMonth} {ShortMonth}</a>
</h2>{block:IfCenterall}</center>{/block:IfCenterall}



    </div><br><br>

    <div class="content text-post">

      {block:Title}<h3><span>{Title}</span></h3>{/block:Title}

      <div class="text">{Body}</div>
    </div>
    {/block:Text}

   {block:Photo}

<div class="meta">


{block:IfCenterall}<center>{/block:IfCenterall}<h2>
<a title="link to this post" href="{Permalink}">{DayOfMonth} {ShortMonth}</a>
</h2>{block:IfCenterall}</center>{/block:IfCenterall}


    </div><br>

    <div class="content photo-post">
      <div class="photo">

        {block:IndexPage}<a href="{Permalink}">{/block:IndexPage}
        {block:PermalinkPage}{LinkOpenTag}{/block:PermalinkPage}
          <img src="{block:IndexPage}{PhotoURL-HighRes}{/block:IndexPage}{block:PermalinkPage}{PhotoURL-HighRes}{/block:PermalinkPage}" alt="{PhotoAlt}">
        {block:IndexPage}</a>{/block:IndexPage}
        {block:PermalinkPage}{LinkCloseTag}{/block:PermalinkPage}

      </div>



      {block:Caption}<div class="caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}
    </div>
    {/block:Photo}



{block:Photoset}

        <div class="meta">


{block:IfCenterall}<center>{/block:IfCenterall}<h2>
<a title="link to this post" href="{Permalink}">{DayOfMonth} {ShortMonth}</a>
</h2>{block:IfCenterall}</center>{/block:IfCenterall}


    </div><br>

    <div class="content photo-post">
      <div class="photo">


       {block:IfLargePhotoset}{Photoset-700}{/block:IfLargePhotoset}

       {block:IfNotLargePhotoset}{block:Photos} <div class="single"><img src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}"/></div>{block:Caption}<div class="caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}{/block:Photos}{/block:IfNotLargePhotoset}

      </div>



      {block:Caption}<div class="caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}
    </div>
                {/block:Photoset}


    {block:Quote}

<div class="meta">


{block:IfCenterall}<center>{/block:IfCenterall}<h2>
<a title="link to this post" href="{Permalink}">{DayOfMonth} {ShortMonth}</a>
</h2>{block:IfCenterall}</center>{/block:IfCenterall}


    </div><br><br>
    <div class="content quote-post {Length}-quote">
      <blockquote class="quote">"{Quote}"</blockquote>

      {block:Source}<div class="source">&mdash;&#8194;{Source}</div>{/block:Source}
    </div>
    {/block:Quote}

    {block:Link}

<div class="meta">

{block:IfCenterall}<center>{/block:IfCenterall}<h2>
<a title="link to this post" href="{Permalink}">{DayOfMonth} {ShortMonth}</a>
</h2>{block:IfCenterall}</center>{/block:IfCenterall}



    </div><br><br>
    <div class="content link-post">
      <h3 class="link"><a href="{URL}">{Name}</a>&nbsp&nbsp&#187;</h3>

      {block:Description}<div class="caption">{Description}</div>{/block:Description}
    </div>
    {/block:Link}

    {block:Chat}

<div class="meta">


{block:IfCenterall}<center>{/block:IfCenterall}<h2>
<a title="link to this post" href="{Permalink}">{DayOfMonth} {ShortMonth}</a>
</h2>{block:IfCenterall}</center>{/block:IfCenterall}


    </div><br><br>

    <div class="content chat-post">
      {block:Title}<h3>{Title}</h3>{/block:Title}

      <ol class="chat">
        {block:Lines}<li class="{Alt} speaker{UserNumber}">
          {block:Label}<span class="label">{Label}</span>{/block:Label}
          <span class="line">{Line}</span>
        </li>{/block:Lines}
      </ol>
    </div>
    {/block:Chat}



{block:Video}

<div class="meta">


{block:IfCenterall}<center>{/block:IfCenterall}<h2>
<a title="link to this post" href="{Permalink}">{DayOfMonth} {ShortMonth}</a>
</h2>{block:IfCenterall}</center>{/block:IfCenterall}



    </div><br>
   <div class="content video-post">
       <div class="video">{VideoEmbed-700}</div>
      <div class="vidcaption">{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}<div class="nocaption">&nbsp;</div></div>
    </div>
    {/block:Video}




    {block:Audio}

<div class="meta">


{block:IfCenterall}<center>{/block:IfCenterall}<h2>
<a title="link to this post" href="{Permalink}">{DayOfMonth} {ShortMonth}</a>
</h2>{block:IfCenterall}</center>{/block:IfCenterall}



    </div><br><br>










    <div class="content audio-post">
    {block:IfCenterall}<center>{/block:IfCenterall}
<div class="audiobox">
      <div class="audio">

      {block:AudioEmbed}<div class="wide_audio">{AudioEmbed-640}</div>{/block:AudioEmbed}

</div></div> {block:IfCenterall}</center>{/block:IfCenterall}

 {block:Caption}<div class="caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}
</div>

    {/block:Audio}

<div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>

  </li>

{/block:Posts}


{block:IfDisqusShortname}
    {block:Permalink}
    <div id="disqus">
    <div id="disqus_thread"></div><script type="text/javascript" src="http://disqus.com/forums/{text:Disqus Shortname}/embed.js"></script><noscript><a href="http://{text:Disqus Shortname}.disqus.com/?url=ref">View the discussion thread.</a></noscript>
    </div>
    {/block:Permalink}
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    (function() {
        var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
        var query = '?';
        for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        if(links[i].href.indexOf('#disqus_thread') >= 0) {
        query += 'url' + i + '=' + encodeURIComponent(links[i].href) + '&';
        }
        }
        document.write('<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="http://disqus.com/forums/{text:Disqus Shortname}/get_num_replies.js' + query + '"></' + 'script>');
    })();
    //]]>
    </script>
    {/block:IfDisqusShortname}


</div> <!-- .box -->
      {/block:Posts}



    </div> <!-- .posts -->

    <div style="clear: both"></div>

    {block:PermalinkPage}
    {block:IfShownotesonpermalinkpages}
      {PostNotes}
    {/block:IfShownotesonpermalinkpages}
    {block:PermalinkPage}

    <div style="clear: both;"></div>





</ol>

<div id="footer">

  <div id="pagination">
  {block:Pagination}
    <p class="back">&nbsp;{block:NextPage}
      <a href="{NextPage}">{lang:Next}</a> >>>
    {/block:NextPage}</p>
    <p class="forward">{block:PreviousPage}
     <<< <a href="{PreviousPage}">{lang:Prev}</a>
    {/block:PreviousPage}&nbsp;</p>

  {/block:Pagination}

  {block:PermalinkPagination}
    {block:PreviousPost}<p class="back">
      <a href="{PreviousPost}">{lang:Next}</a> >>>
    </p>{/block:PreviousPost}
    {block:NextPost}<p class="forward">
     <<< <a href="{NextPost}">{lang:Prev}</a>
    {/block:NextPost}</p>
  {/block:PermalinkPagination}

  {block:DayPagination}
    {block:PreviousDayPage}<p class="back">
      <a href="{PreviousDayPage}">{lang:Next}</a> >>>
    {/block:PreviousDayPage}</p>
    {block:NextDayPage}<p class="forward">
      <<< <a href="{NextDayPage}">{lang:Prev}</a>
    </p>{/block:NextDayPage}
  {/block:DayPagination}
  </div>


<br><br />

<center>
<!--<a href="/archive">{lang:Archive}</a> // 
    <a href="/random">{lang:Random post}</a> //
    <a href="{RSS}">{lang:RSS}</a> 
<br />
<font size="2"><i>{lang:Powered by Tumblr 2} - 
    <a href="http://www.tumblr.com/theme/9601">Quite Big theme</a> by <a href="http://georgedunkley.tumblr.com/">George Dunkley</a></i></font></center>-->



</div>

</div>

</body>
<div style=" opacity:0.0;"> 
</html>
```

Suggest changes to be done to remove the 2 buttons.
I'm not into web designing.

Comment: Try `document.getElementById("iframe_controls").style.display = "none"`

Answer (score 2):

### Disable Tumblr Controls

To disable the top right controls ( follow abc / user ) you can disable the promotion option on the `customise` screen.

1. Log in to **Tumblr**
2. Click **Settings**
3. Click **Customise**
4. On the left hand pane, click **Advanced**
5. Uncheck **Promote Tumblr**

This will disable the Tumblr Controls for none Tumblr users, however, Tumblr users will still get the controls.

The reason, these controls are really a short cut for a logged in user, and I would advise against hiding them, however this is possible. If you add the following to your Custom CSS box:

```
#tumblr_controls, .controls {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Normally I wouldn't condone using `!important` but the Tumblr embed really does some funky things, so in this case brute force is needed.

Hope that helps.